# Qualtrics - how to read and set choice values

Tags: qualtrics

I'm trying to set choice values using javascript. First, I'm trying to get the question choice values. 
For this, I call

```
var choices = this.getChoices( "radio" )
firstChoice = choices[0]
secondChoice =choices[1]
```

I get 1,2 for firstChoice and secondChoice, respectively; however, these are not the values/captions of the choices. How can I get the real values/captions?

Then, I'd love to set the new values for these choices. Specifically, I want to add 3 to each one of the values. How can I do that? Manh thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "real values/captions" do you mean the choice text, the choice value (true/false), or the choice recode?

Comment: The choice text, sorry for being unclear in my question

Comment: OK, that helps.  Now, if you want the choice text, what do you want to add 3 to?

Comment: Say that the firstChoice's text is 10. I want it to be 13. Likewise, if secondChoice's text is 20, I'd like the user to see 23. I'm missing 2 things here: 1- how to programmatically retrieve the text of the choices; 2- how to programmatically modify these texts

Comment: There must be something you are leaving out, because on its face it doesn't make sense...you could just change the choice text in Qualtrics.  Anyway, the Qualtrics functions aren't going to help you. Your script needs to find and update the html elements (the radio button labels). Make use of prototypejs to make that easier. Your code will probably have to take differences between JFE and SE into account unless you are always using SE. Give it a shot and update the question if you run into issues.